# pointwise convergence of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am a bit confused. I have heard today someone saying that the Fourier series of any continues periodic function $f$, say with period 1 for concreteness, converges pointwise to $f$. Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series) explicitly says otherwise, but claims that the proof is not constructive and somewhat advanced. So what is it?

I have to apologize for this question, since I could just pick any book about Fourier analysis and check it up myself, but since the answer is a simple "yes" or "no" I hope it is not to much of an effort to answer this for someone how knows the answer.

Comment: On Page 83 of Stein-Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis, they give an example of a continuous period function $f$ whose Fourier series diverges at a point.

Comment: In general it's not true. You need some additional hypotheses that in most of concrete examples are satisfied, for instance that it has bounded variation.

Comment: It's only true of "nice" continuous functions, eg. with piecewise continuous derivatives, which are the ones that one spontaneously (naively?) thinks of as continuous functions, and often finds in applications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Theorem 2.2 in [this pdf](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Estein/lehre/SoSem08/Conv_Fs.pdf) which shows (the proof is not really complete) that there is a continuous periodic function with divergent fourier series in some point. The first example of such a function was given by DuBois-Reymond in 1873, in the meantime this has even been [extended](http://www.math.ku.dk/kurser/2009-10/blok1/fouan/fouan.pdf) (see the note on page 13):

> For every null set $N \subset ]-\pi,\pi]$ there is a continuous
> periodic function for which the Fourier series is divergent in each
> point of $N$.

Shown in Y. Katznelson, An introduction to harmonic analysis. Wiley 1968.

Comment: Thanks! This is very nice.