# Conditions such that $f\leq g$ implies $FourierSeries(f)\leq FourierSeries(g)$

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-series

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions of period $2\pi$ and let $f\leq g$. I wonder the conditions on $f,g$ which guarantee the ineqality $FS(f)\leq FS(g)$, where $FS$ denote Fourier series of a function.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous... no problem...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any reference or proof available?

Comment: $f$ continuous $\implies f=FS(f)$, plainly. See the main convergence theorem on Fourier series. Problems arise when you have jumps... and I  have some doubt there exists theorems warranting that $f<g \implies FS(f) < FS(g)$

Comment: The problem is with Gibbs phenomenon (you must have heard about it) at discontinuity points.

Comment: In Stein's book(Fourier Analysis : An Introduction, page 83),  example of 
a continuous function whose Fourier series does not converge is given.

Comment: By continuous, I mean continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$. If your function $f$ is build by periodizing a function $\varphi$ defined on $[0,2 \pi]$ but with $\varphi(0) \neq \varphi(2 \pi)$, you have a jump and many things can arrive...

Comment: I am a bit confused by these:

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77855/pointwise-convergence-of-fourier-series

Comment: I beg your pardon, I  was wrong, we have to assume $f \in C^1$ for warranting $f=FS(f)$. $f \in C^0$ isn't enough.

Comment: not problem, thanks for your valuable helps